# Setting width of my button removes text label

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a set of buttons made in a for loop like this:

```
text_list = []
for character in string.ascii_lowercase:
    button = Button(window, text=character)
    button.config(command=lambda button=button: button_pressed(button))
    button.place(x=location, y=0)
    location += 25
    text_list.append(button)
```

The result is this:
[image]

But as soon as I add a width parameter:

```
text_list = []
for character in string.ascii_lowercase:
    button = Button(window, text=character, width=20)
    button.config(command=lambda button=button: button_pressed(button))
    button.place(x=location, y=0)
    location += 20
    text_list.append(button)
```

...the text labels disappear:
[image]

I have tried using a separate `button.config` but that doesn't work either. Any solution would be appreciated!

Comment: Try changing `button.place(x=location, y=0)` to `button.pack(side="left")`

Comment: Also you know that the `width` parameter is in text characters not pixels. So basically you have buttons with `text="          a         "` and the buttons overlap.

Comment: `Button` by default uses the width of '0' of the font used to do the calculation for the buttons width. If you want to use pixels, you have to force an image onto the `Button`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...the text labels dissappear:

It does not disappear, what you see is buttons stacked on top of each other, with text at the center of these long buttons. The reason why buttons are longer than your expected 20px is that, buttons by default takes does not take pixels. It uses the '0' of the font that is used with the widget for size calculations.

To force it to use pixel calculation, you have to pass an image that `tkinter` understands and its not hard:

```
puedo_img = PhotoImage(master=window,height=1,width=1)
for character in string.ascii_lowercase:
    button = Button(window, text=character,image=puedo_img, width=20, compound='center')
    .....
```

We use `compound` to show both, the text and the graphic(image).

Comment: @RAW_tech Yes it does, try it on, you will notice.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, and it makes sense, but for some reason I get the error:
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
This error appeared in the button = Button(window.... line rather than the first line

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error now:
_tkinter.TclError: images may not be named the same as the main window

Comment: @RAW_tech Try again now?